# Rails - Query with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am currently trying to create a custom method on a model, where the conditions used are those of a has_many association. The method I have so far is:

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchases

  def inventory
    inventory = Vehicle.where(:purchases => self.purchases)
    return inventory
  end

end
```

This is not working, due to the fact that Vehicle has_many :purchases (thus there is no column "purchases" on the vehicle model). How can I use the vehicle.purchases array as a condition in this kind of query?

To complicate matters, the has_many is also polymorphic, so I can not simply use a `.join(:purchases)` element on the query, as there is no VehiclePurchase model.

EDIT: For clarity, the relevant parts of my purchase model and vehicle models are below:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dealer_id, :purchase_type_id

  belongs_to :purchase_item_type, :polymorphic => true

end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :purchases, :as => :purchase_item_type

end
```

Comment: Please add the polymorphic associations you mention.

Comment: I have added the relevant models showing the associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using the :source and :source_type options on the Vehicle model, which allows polymorphic parents to be associated.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def inventory
    Vehicle.where(:id => purchases.where(:purchase_item_type_type => "Vehicle").map(&:purchase_item_type_id))
  end
end
```

Or:

```
  def inventory
    purchases.includes(:purchase_item_type).where(:purchase_item_type_type => "Vehicle").map(&:purchase_item_type)
  end
```

Comment: This already exists - I have updated the question for clarity. I'm not sure how this answer helps; the purchases association on the dealer works fine, the problem is with the vehicle model.

Comment: By using `has_many :vehicles, through :purchases`, you get vehicles associated to the dealer's purchases. That's what I understood you wanted.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your answer - this would work, except that purchases has a polymorphic belongs_to with regard to vehicles (question edited for clarity), and thus I can not add has_many :vehicles to purchases since a purchase does not necessarily belong_to a vehicle.